# Google Storage access denied on file with parentheses

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, boto

I'm getting a `GSResponseError: 403 Access denied` when querying files that have a parentheses on their name. I'm using Google App Engine and boto.

For example:

```
key_id = "caffeine-crystals-big (1).jpg"
bucket_id = "000-403-error"

connection = boto.connect_gs("...", "...")
bucket = connection.get_bucket(bucket_id)
key = bucket.get_key(key_id)  # ERROR
```

Raises: `GSResponseError: GSResponseError: 403 Access denied to 'gs://bucket-foo/key-bar (2).jpg'`

It only happens if the file has a parentheses on it's name and only if I try it from Google App Engine. From localhost and dev_appserver it works fine.

**EDIT:**

You can try the following files:

gs://000-403-error/caffeine-crystals-big (1).jpg

gs://000-403-error/caffeine-crystals-big.jpg

Both have public read permission. Both can be retrieved from my local machine running dev_appserver and boto. But once I deploy the app to GAE, `caffeine-crystals-big (1).jpg` can't be read.

Comment: Are you sure the acl is set correctly on these files? This error indicates that you don't have access privileges to read these files.

Comment: Why are you using `boto` and not GCS client library? (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)

Comment: @AndreiVolgin It just happens with files with parentheses in the name, not with the other files. And all are being created the same way.

Comment: @Kekito It's legacy code. I think that by the time it was implemented boto was faster than GCS. Not sure by now though.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I've put ACL to public read and the problem persists. What is the most weird is that from my local machine it can be read with no problem but it raises 403 error from GAE

Comment: Can you read this file by simply putting the full path and file name into your browser window?

Comment: Yes, http://storage.googleapis.com/000-403-error/caffeine-crystals-big%20(1).jpg and from gsutil gs://000-403-error/caffeine-crystals-big\ \(1\).jpg